# Workarounds for Safari ITP 2.3

Tags: safari, mobile-safari

I am very confused as to how Safari 2.3 works in certain respects, and why sites can’t easily circumvent it. I don’t understand under what circumstances limits are applied, what the exact limits are, to what they are applied, and for how long.

To clarify my question I broke it down into several cases. I will be referring to Apple’s official blog post about ITP 2.3 [1] which you can quote from, but feel free to link to any other authoritative or factually correct sources in your answer.

**For third-party sites loaded in iframes:**

1. Why can’t they just use localStorage to store the values of cookies, and send this data along not as actual browser cookies, but as data in the body of the request? Similarly, they can parse the response to updaye localStorage. What limits does ITP actually place on localStorage in third party iframes?
2. If the localStorage is frequently purged (see question 1), why can’t they simply use postMessage to tell a script on the enclosing website to store some information (perhaps encrypted) and then spit it back whenever it loads an iframe?

**For sites that use link decoration**

3. I still don’t understand what the limits on localStorage are in third party sites in iframes, which did NOT get classified as link decorator sites. But let’s say they are link decorator sites. According to [1] Apple only start limiting stuff further if there is a querystring or fragment. But can’t a website rather trivially store this information in the URL path before the querystring, ie `/in/here` without `?in=here` … certainly large companies like Google can trivially choose to do that?
4. In the case a site has been labeled as a tracking site, does that mean all its non-cookie data is limited to 7 days? What about cookies set by the server, aren’t they exempted? So then simply make a request to your server to set the cookie instead of using Javascript. After all, the operator of the site is very likely to also have access to its HTTP server and app code.

**For all sites**

5. Why can’t a service like Google Analytics or Facebook’s widgets simply convince a site to additional add a CNAME to their DNS and get Google’s and Facebook’s servers under a subdomain like gmail.mysite.com or analytics.mysite.com ? And then boom, they can read and set cookies again, in some cases even on the top-level domain for website owners who don’t know better. Doesn’t this completely defeat the goals of Apple’s ITP, since Google and Facebook have now become a “second party” in some sense?
6. Here on StackOverflow, when we log out on iOS Safari the StackOverflow network is able to [log out of multiple sites at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvOLp.jpg) … how is that even accomplished if no one can track users across websites? I have heard it said that “second party cookies” still can be stored but what exactly makes a second party cookie different from a third party?

My question is broken down into 6 cases but the overall theme is, in each case: how does Apple’s latest ITP work in that case, and how does it actually block all cases of potentially malicious tracking (to the point where a well-funded company can’t just do the workarounds above) while at the same time allowing legitimate use cases?

[1] https://webkit.org/blog/9521/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does Safari ITP do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73794780/what-exactly-does-safari-itp-do)